# Hide Data Filter using CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to hide some of the Data Filters which appears as menu items.  I would prefer to use CSS as I do not know much about Javascript or PHP.

This is the web page

https://drfixit.tech/repairs/huawei-smart-phone/

The Data Filter presents Huawei P, Huawei Phone, Huawei Mate & Huawei Honor options.  I want to hide Huawei Phone using the CSS command Display:None;

Comment: Please provide your source code, including the HTML + the CSS you've attempted to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.projects-filter li[data-filter=".nproject-category-huawei-smart-phone"] {
    display: none;
}
```